# Suppress blank line from robocopy in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I use robocopy in a PowerShell script to circumvent limitations of the PowerShell using very long path names (more than 260 characters). The program robocopy is invoked as

```
robocopy /E /NP /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS $Source $Destination
```

This invocation suppresses all this verbose output of robocopy but will allow to show any error. Unfortunately robocopy still outputs one single blank line. Since the robocopy output is put to my log file I want to suppress this single blank line.

- Is there a way to tell robocopy to produce **no output** on normal operation?
- Is there a war to suppress this tiny nasty line with PowerShell?

**Edit:** It's clear that it's not easy to implement this in a kind of post-processing. But it would be nice if only the single line would be filtered out. If robocopy outputs some lines (including errors), it's not necessary to suppress all empty lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter empty lines with command like below:

```
robocopy /E /NP /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS $Source $Destination | findstr /r /v "^$"
```

Comment: This will suppress any empty line. If would be nice to suppress only the single line output, but for the current use case it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can share the output?

From what I understand (and could be way off hence why asking for the output) you're not getting errors, you just want sweet, sweet nothing. In which case we'd use out-null

```
& robocopy /E /NP /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS $Source $Destination | out-null
```

As an example:

```
get-item c:\users | out-null
```

will give you nothing at all.

apologies if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: This will suppress all output of robocopy. This doesn't match the requirement "but will allow to show any error". I've verified your proposal and see that errors are suppressed too.